# Función Typescript + Ajax

Tags: ajax, typescript

Me gustaría saber si es posible llamar a una función en Typescript dentro del sucess de Ajax y, si es posible, de que manera hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La línea subrayada en rojo es la función en Typescript. Cuando ejecuto la página me lanza el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu funcion `lista_resultados_return` ? Y de paso añádele la propiedad [context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) de esta menera: `context: this` al metodo ajax y haber que tal.

Comment: Estás perdiendo el contexto. Define la función success usando la *notación flecha* y te funcionará

Comment: la función lista_resultados_return es para test, tan solo tiene un console.log.

Comment: En cuanto a la notación flecha..te refieres así?? success: (data) => { }

Comment: Si, a eso me refiero